# Can't find module (Error: Cannot find module 'events/chat')

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am getting the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'events/chat'
```

I have the following folder/file structure:

```
└─┬ chat
  ├─+─ events
  | +── chat.js
  | +── moderation.js
  ├─ index.js
```

But if I only call the **chat.js** or **moderation.js** file in my **server.js** file it works just fine.

**index.js:**

```
const chatEvent = require('events/chat');
const moderation = require('events/moderation');

module.exports = {
  chatEvent,
  moderation,
};
```

Comment: `events` is a built-in `Node.JS` module... That may be why Node can't find it.

Comment: I already tried by renaming `events` to `eventsName` and I still got the same error.

Comment: Try `require('./events/chat')`